# Update OSX Vim using MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to update Vim (for use in Terminal) on my Mac. It's currently running version 7.3, but YouCompleteMe requires Vim 7.3.584, and won't run even though it's installed.

I've tried using a Vim alias in my .bash_profile:

```
alias vim='/Users/Conor/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
```

However none of my Vim plugins are launched when I run Vim like this, any my vimrc file isn't recognised either.

How can I get this alias to recognise my existing Vim settings? Or is there a better way of upgrading Vim for mac?

Comment: I download a macvim and mine is ok，what is that when you type `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*.tbz` that you downloaded from [the official page](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases) contains a `mvim` script.

Once you have moved that script somewhere in your `$PATH` you can start the MacVim GUI like this:

```
$ mvim filename
```

and the MacVim CLI like that:

```
$ mvim -v filename
```

From there the only thing you need is to change your alias to point to `mvim`:

```
alias vim='mvim -v'
```

The original built-in Vim and its runtime files stay untouched, MacVim uses its own runtime files located in the `MacVim.app` bundle and both honor your personal config (assuming they are located where they should be: `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/`).

Quick, clean and painless.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed MacVim with HomeBrew you can use

```
brew install macvim --override-system-vim
```

Comment: Running that command still doesn't replace the systems vim, and the binaries it downloads (to /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72) still don't use the vimrc file or any of my addons

Answer (score 1):

If you just want pure vim with python support do:

`brew install vim --override-system-vim --HEAD`

I had the same issue as you, but this worked like a charm. You complete me works perfectly after this.